# Formal proof market incompleteness under jump diffusion

Tags: hedging, merton-model, jump-diffusion

Does anyone have formal proof of markets incompleteness under jump diffusion ?

I am familiar with the intuitive approach as mentioned in Tankov (delta), yet I am looking for a formal approach and some reference paper  :)

Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "formal proof". In a complete market you can insure for any future contingency. To prove *in*completeness it suffices to show one counterexample of this. I have not read Tankov, but if he gives just one example, it suffices.